# Play 2.2.1 Java: Whats the equivalent of @before filters from play 1.X?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to implement a ***setUserIfPresent***() method that puts a user object into the context like Http.Context.current().args.put("user", user);

This method should be applied **before** every controller method so that views have access implicit access to the user.

With Play1 I create a ***BaseController*** that **invokes** this method **before** all requests (@Before filter) and **extended** all other controllers from this one.

**How to achieve something like this in play2 using Java API?**

Seems like there is something for Scala but for Java? http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaHttpFilters

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *could* use filters ([or Interceptors](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaInterceptors)) in the "traditional" webapp framework way, the Play-preferred way seems to definitely be to compose custom `Action` methods; see the documentation on [Action Composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActionsComposition).

If you follow their style, you'll define a new `Action` implementation like this:

```
public class UserContextInjectingAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {

    public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        Logger.info("Injecting user data into context " + ctx);
        injectUser(ctx); // Written by you
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }

}
```

And you'd end up with controller code that looks like this:

```
@With(UserContextInjectingAction.class)
public static Result showHomePage() {
    return ok("Welcome");
}
```

Comment: how to use UserContextInjectingAction in play scala, my app mixed with java and scala classes. I have play.mvc.Action.Simple extended class now I want use same for scala controller