# cannot find the symbol @Before in play2.2.1 java

Tags: java, playframework, controller, interceptor

I am trying to use @Before interceptor in my controller

```
 @Before(only = {"save" })
 static void parseParams() {
    String[] jobcategories = params.getAll("jobcategories");
    for (int i = 0; i < jobcategories.length; i++) {
        params.put("jobcategories[" + i + "].id", jobcategories[i]);
    }
    System.out.print(jobcategories);
 }
```

but it gives me compile time error

```
 C:\myapp\app\controllers\JobAdController.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
     @Before(only={"save"})
      ^
   symbol:   class Before
   location: class JobAdController
 C:\myapp\app\controllers\JobAdController.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
         String[] jobcategories = params.getAll("jobcategories");
                                  ^
   symbol:   variable params
   location: class JobAdController
 C:\myapp\app\controllers\JobAdController.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
             params.put("jobcategories["+i+"].id",jobcategories[i]);
             ^
   symbol:   variable params
   location: class JobAdController
 Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
 3 errors
 (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
 Total time: 30 s, completed Nov 20, 2014 1:05:18 PM
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN'T find it as it's from Play 1.x API @Before and other interceptors are NOT available in Play 2.x - they are replaced by [Action Composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActionsComposition)

[@See similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20072380/1066240)

Note: Do not use documentation of Play 1.x for Play 2.x at all. In most areas they are totally different.